# Toggle swap of alt and win keys with command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-tweaks

I know I can swap alt and win keys using the `gnome-tweak-tool`. However, I have to do this often, because I move between keyboards frequently, so it would be nice to have a script solution.

There is a simple way to find out which dconf settings a given change corresponds to, by using the command `dconf watch /` in terminal and then issuing the change, which leads to the terminal printing out the corresponding change. [see https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-script-the-settings-made-by-gnome-tweak-tool/]

In this way, I have found out that the change I need is to toggle (remove or add) the entry `'altwin:swap_alt_win'` in

```
/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options 
  ['ctrl:aa_ctrl', 'grp:shift_caps_toggle', 'altwin:swap_alt_win']
```

The linked webpage recommends using `gsettings` for this, but it's not clear to me how to do this.
Running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` does indeed return the setting, but I'm stuck on how I can now toggle the option `'altwin:swap_alt_win'`. I think one should use `set`, but to I'd have to search the list for the term and add or remove it, depending on whether it exists? Is there are different way?

Incidentally, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options ['ctrl:aa_ctrl', 'grp:shift_caps_toggle']` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:aa_ctrl', 'grp:shift_caps_toggle']"
```

To toggle on and off, you will need to create a little bash script that tests what the current setting is, then sets the other setting. You can read out the key with

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

You can then bind the script to a hotkey to toggle quickly.

The script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options)
case $STATUS in
    "@as []" )
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:aa_ctrl', 'grp:shift_caps_toggle']"
    ;;
    "['ctrl:aa_ctrl', 'grp:shift_caps_toggle']" )
        gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: thanks a lot. This fixes the last point I was making. However, it's still not clear to me how I would toggle in between having the `'altwin:swap_alt_win'` option on and off.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked the toggling aspect. I added a possible script based on my script to toggle tap to click. I did not test. Please test and let me know any corrections where needed.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't do anything. I can't seem to find a `'altwin:swap_alt_win'` in your solution. Also it only works if the list is exactly the one tested right?

Comment: Update the arguments. I have just copied the last one you mentioned in your answer

Answer (score 4):

I know its a bit late but I had the same problem with a mac-like external keyboard, a quick solution to switch between the two settings can be two aliases in your .bashrc, I know a toggle could be more elegant but this is okay for me.

```
alias swaplap="gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \"['caps:ctrl_modifier', 'lv3:ralt_switch']\""
alias swapkb="gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \"['caps:ctrl_modifier', 'lv3:ralt_switch', 'altwin:swap_alt_win']\""
```

In my case, when using the external keyboard I just launch `swapkb` form terminal, `swaplap` revert the setting back.
Also, please note that I have control mapped on caps lock, in your case your aliases might look like this:

```
alias swaplap="gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \"['ctrl:aa_ctrl', 'grp:shift_caps_toggle']\""
alias swapkb="gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \"['ctrl:aa_ctrl', 'grp:shift_caps_toggle', 'altwin:swap_alt_win']\""
```